# Why am I getting a command not found for Padrino?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino, gemfile

EDIT: This seems to work on my CentOS machine but not my Ubuntu box.

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ which padrino
/usr/bin/padrino
$ which padrino-gen
/usr/bin/padrino-gen
```

I started playing with Sinatra but when I started thinking about some admin/authentication support I was lead to Padrino.

Problem is as follows.

I ran:

```
sudo gem install padrino
```

but then when I ran the create command, I got a command not found issue:

```
$ padrino g project demo-app
padrino: command not found
```

This seems to work in my directory where I created my heroku app because there's a gemfile there so I can run `bundle exec` before the `padrino` command. But shouldn't I be able to create a padrino project without a gemfile??

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's with not using Bundler?

Comment: I'm just testing this out of the box. The padrino homepage has 5 commands to starting a new app. No mention of using Bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me in Ubuntu 11.04

```
# Setup Ubuntu LTS 10.4
sudo apt-get install ruby 
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev 
sudo apt-get install sqlite 
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install irb
sudo apt-get install rdoc
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
sudo apt-get install g++
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/69365/rubygems-1.3.6.tgz
>tar zxvf rubygems-1.3.6.tgz 
cd rubygems-1.3.6
sudo ruby setup.rb
sudo gem1.8 install rake rspec padrino --no-ri --no-rdoc
padrino g project foo -d activerecord -b
padrino g admin
padrino rake ar:setup
```

ref: https://gist.github.com/1016133

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the following helped me out:
Simply just restarted my terminal.

If it is not feasible in your case, try to source your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`.

Environment managers like *rbenv*, *rvm* unfortunately require this step.

Answer (score 0):

pretty strange, try with:

```
sudo gem install padrino-gen
```

If doesn't help try to directly

```
padrino-gen project demo-app
```

Comment: >$ sudo gem install padrino-gen
>Successfully installed padrino-gen-0.10.7
>1 gem installed
>Installing ri documentation for padrino-gen-0.10.7...
>Installing RDoc documentation for padrino-gen-0.10.7...
>$ padrino-gen project demo-app
>padrino-gen: command not found

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your env, are you using rvm or rbenv or the default system ruby?

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your env... post `which gem`, `which padrino`, `which padrino-gen`

Comment: can you try to run directly `/usr/bin/padrino-gen` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and fixed it by copying this command from the .bash_profile file which was created when I installed RVM, and adding it to the end of my .bashrc:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```